# Vagrant Chef path for importing database

Tags: database, import, chef-infra, vagrant

I have learned a lot about setting up vagrant with chef and I am hitting a wall since I am new to ruby - vagrant - chef and I am not the biggest developer. Being mostly front end but trying to set up a better environment to develop in.

I have searched and found great answers but left with one final question.

I have this code creating the database but I can not figure out where to place the database to import from...

```
# import an sql dump from your app_root/data/dump.sql to the my_database database
execute "import" do
  command "mysql -u root -p\"#{node['mysql']['server_root_password']}\" my_database < /chef/vagrant_db/database-name.mysql"
  action :run
end
```

So I need to know where the path should start from, the top level home directory, from the top level folder where I run vagrant up? Where it is currently and a few other tried places is not working.

Any ideas would be great. I have search google so much so that I am almost ready to give up.

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]` for this. Let's say you want to get that SQL file from a remote web server:

```
db = File.join(Chef::Config[:file_cache_path], 'database.mysql')

remote_file db do
  source   'http://my.web.server/db.mysql
  action   :create_if_missing
  notifies :run, 'execute[import]', :immediately
end

execute "import" do
  command "mysql -u root -p\"#{node['mysql']['server_root_password']}\" my_database < #{db}"
  action :nothing
end
```

This will:

1. Add idempotency - meaning it won't try to import the database on each run
2. Leverage Chef's file-cache-path, which is persisted and guaranteed to be writable on supported Chef systems
3. Extensible (you could easily change `remote_file` to `cookbook_file` or some custom resource to fetch the database)

Now, getting the file from Vagrant is a different story. By default, Vagrant mounts the directory where the `Vagrantfile` is located at on the host (local laptop) at `/vagrant` on the VM (guest machine). You can mount additional locations (called "shared folders") anywhere on your local laptop.

#### Bonus

If you are running the database on your local machine, you can actually share the socket over a shared folder with Vagrant :). Then you don't even need MySQL on your VM - it will use the one running on your host laptop.

Sources:

- I write a lot of Chef :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to explain. That would have taken me a while to figure out. If you could share a link or two, maybe a tutorial I will start investigating both options, the shared folder for the localhost database and code above.

So a question as well, the code above, does that go into the cookbooks/mysql/recipes/default.rb - file?

As for the shared folder. I think I have one set up. So in the code above if I add the path do I start /vagrant/shared-folder/database.mysql ?

Comment: I don't have any tutorials or guides. I recommend the learnchef tutorials (https://learnchef.opscode.com). The code can go in any recipe you want, you just need to include that recipe in your run_list.